# The "Speak Text" feature in Okular is not working. How do I get it to work?

Tags: software-recommendation, okular, text-to-speech

I'm currently using Ubuntu 18.04 and Okular for viewing pdf documents. I thought it would be convenient if I could use the *text to speech* feature. I tried following all the instructions given here: http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/listen_your_books_epub_pdf_okular/ (which was the only source I could find online) and I'm yet unable to get the text-to-speech feature working. Can you please tell me what should I do to get this working? If it is not possible because it was deprecated, can you please recommend a good alternative?

I tried opening the application from the terminal to listen to the audio. This was the output on the terminal when I selected a part of the text and clicked "Speak Text":

```
using null output device, none available
qt.speech.tts.flite: "Failed to start audio output (error 1)"
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `pdf` file contains text? There might be pages, that consist of [scanned] images. Install `poppler-utils` and run `pdftotext your-file.pdf /dev/stdout` - Is there any output to the terminal window? If you get output, you can install `espeak` and run `pdftotext your-file.pdf /dev/stdout | espeak`. I tested that it works right now. You prefer to store the output text in a file, and `grep` paragraphs from that file to `espeak`. Tip: `pdftotext your-file.pdf` (without output file name and redirection) will write to the file `your-file.txt`.

Comment: @sudodus Yes I ensured that the pdf contains text. And Thanks! I'll try using espeak and pdftotext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Program packages

Install two packages

```
sudo apt install poppler-utils espeak
```

### Copy and paste text

If you can

- copy and paste a piece of text from a `pdf` document directly or
- create a text file `your-file.txt` with

  ```
  pdftotext your-file.pdf
  ```

  and open the text file in a text editor and copy a piece of text from there,

then you can paste the piece of text into a terminal window, where `espeak` is running.

```
$ espeak
```

or if there is annoying warning output

```
$ espeak 2>/dev/null
```

Press Enter and `espeak` will wait for input from the terminal, so copy and paste some text from your pdf file in `okular` (or from some other program as illustrated with your question's title in my `firefox`,

```
The “Speak Text” feature in Okular is not working. How do I get it to work?
```

Press Enter to start reading aloud. Copy and paste some other pieces of text and press Enter to listen to them. Quit from `espeak` with ctrl C.

See the screenshot:

[image]

### Pipe text into `espeak`

You can redirect the output into `espeak` and listen to all the text from a `pdf` file,

```
pdftotext your-file.pdf /dev/stdout | espeak
```

or if you have a text file, read from it directly,

```
< your-file.txt espeak
```

or if you want a talking clock

```
LC_TIME=C date '+%A, %B, %-d, %Y; %H and %M' | espeak
```

Comment: This doesn't make okular text-to-speech feature to work!

Comment: @MuhammadYusuf, No but it is a workaround, that was useful for the original poster.

Comment: really you expect us to copy & paste each time??? it's ridiculous absolutely, It can not be a correct answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Qt Multimedia module is not installed by default so you are required to install it.

```
sudo apt install qml-module-qtmultimedia
```

Comment: doesn't work for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: This worked fine for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I followed [this instruction set](https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2018/12/text-to-speech-on-gnulinux-part-2-okular-to-speech.html) successfully.

> Install the dispatcher:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install speech-dispatcher
> ```
>
> Install the synthesizer:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install espeak
> ```
>
> Install the speech plugin for Okular:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install qtspeech5-speechd-plugin
> ```
>
> Note: in this moment the version of Qt is 5. In the future, when you still read this article, you may find the version changed and the package version or name changed as well. This article is based only on current version.
>
> Run the dispatcher first:
>
> ```
> speech-dispatcher -d
> ```
>
> You must run Okular after speech-dispatcher.

Comment: This worked too for me.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else works (which was the case for me), I made a small python program which glues together pdftotext, espeak and aplay: [pdf2speech](https://github.com/Nitwix/pdf2speech)

It's not as good as having the integration with okular, but it works.