# How do I get screenreader Orca to read out loud a whole page of a pdf document on click or key shortcut?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, pdf, accessibility, orca

I run Ubuntu 18.04 and have installed version 3.28.0 of the [Orca screenreader](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/orca.1.html) with `sudo apt-get install gnome-orca`.

When I start Orca and open a PDF document, it reads its file name out loud, and navigation moves inside the document (such as the items of the context menu when I click right on the PDF page). However, I cannot get it to read the contents of the page until the end of the chosen page. Instead, when I highlight text with a left click, it reads just this text - twice, once when highlighted and again when un-highlighted.

How can I get it to read a whole page (once)?

Comment: You tried universal access ?

Comment: Maybe you can use the method with `espeak` that is described in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098171/the-speak-text-feature-in-okular-is-not-working-how-do-i-get-it-to-work/1098404#1098404).